# Balls out of a sack

Tags: combinatorics

To understand combinatorics better I formulated a question for myself (not homework!), that I'm trying to solve:

Imagine a sack with 6 red balls, 5 yellow balls and 4 blue balls. Pick six of them without laying them back. What is the probability that at least 2 of the six balls are yellow and at least 1 is red. (The other three balls can be anything.)

First I'd find out how many possibilities there are to pick three different balls. Here I'm not sure how to do it. My first guess would be $\binom{6+5+4}{3}$ but I think its less because we have multiple balls of each color?

Then I would need to find how many possibilities there are so that three balls are so that 2 are yellow and 1 is red. Maybe it's $\binom{5}{2}\cdot\binom{6}{1}$?

Then we would have to divide those values.

Answer (score 2):

There are $\binom{15}6$ ways to choose any $6$ balls from the $15=4+5+6$ balls that we have.

How many ways to choose $6$ balls in such way that at least $1$ is red and at least $2$ are yellow? Let us calculate the opposite thing, it would be easier.

If we pick $0$ red balls, we have to choose all $6$ balls from yellow and blue. So there are $\binom96$ ways to do that.

If we pick $0$ yellow balls, than the number of ways is $\binom{10}6$. If we pick exactly $1$ yellow ball, the number of combinations is $\binom{10}5$.

Note that none of the combinations mentioned above coincide. It can’t be that we picked $0$ red and $0$ yellow balls. As well as it can’t be that we picked $0$ red and exactly $1$ yellow ball.

So the answer is $$\frac{\binom{15}6-\binom96-\binom{10}6-\binom{10}5}{15\choose6}=\frac{49}{55}.$$